# HMS: After integration of Huawei Ads kit the ads are not displaying

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I am facing issue related to Huawei Ads kit, after integration of Huawei Ads kit the Ads are not displaying and getting error code : 204.

Please find screenshot of meta-data tag which I added in manifest file :[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. As I can see screenshot which you shared, currently you are using Lite SDK in order to get more Ads, you can integrate full Ad SDK.
2. Error code 204 refers no matching Adverts.